# HTTPS and file_get_contents

Tags: php, https, openssl, file-get-contents

I am trying to read a remote website offering some JSON objects using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file-get-contents). The connection should be encrypted so I try connecting using HTTPS.

```
<?php

$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "api.crt",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($arrContextOptions);

$jsonObjects = file_get_contents('https://example.com', false, $context);

?>
```

However, the connection fails with the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112) in api-read.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in api-read.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://example.com): failed to open stream: operation failed in api-read.php on line 13
```

The sources I found so far mentioned different possible causes.

- **Using wrong protocol versions.** AFAIK you can only disallow certain protocols using the *cipher* option. PHP should support SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLSv1.0, correct? I verified by using curl on the command line that the remote machine accepts connections using SSLv3.
- **CN mismatch** The CN mentioned in the certificate is the IP address I am connecting to.

So far I could not solve the issue or find any helpful information. I am running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is another option. Just don't fiddle with the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFY...` options in production.

Comment: Try to use SNI by using `SNI_enabled`, see http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: @SteffenUllrich enabling SNI had no effect